# Xamarin Update from VS.NET 2015 does not install?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to update Xamarin thru VS.NET 2015 ENT from Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check Now.
A pop-up with Xamarin 4.1.1.3 and "Download Complete".
When pressing Install button, nothing happens.

How to?

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: Be sure you are running VS with administrator previledges

Comment: I did but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check localcache(c: drive) -> Xamarin folder -> exe is available or not  or  Better way goto your Xamarin login , download the update and install

Comment: Where can I find localcache on Windows 10?

Comment: C drive appdata\local\xamarin or Xamarinstudio folder